# How to improve this AS3 code structure to be more effective?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, addeventlistener

I have made an AS3 code to be a function. But I think my code is too lengthy. Could you help to improve it? Thank you!

I created test.fla first and added 5 grey block(external pictures from PSD) to stage. My function is to display different pictures when hovering mouse on corresponding grey block.

I converted those 5 grey blocks to Movie Clip and set instance name as sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4 and sp5. Then I created a document class, test.as and set 5 EventListener.

```
sp1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse1);
sp2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse2);
sp3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse3);
sp4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse4);
sp5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse5);
```

So my first question is can I have any method to combine those 5 EventListener to be one? Because in my mind, so many EventListener will cost much more resource of PC.

My second question is I set 5 target pictures as 5 class.

In test.as I created code below:

```
public class EuroCup extends Sprite{
    var arr:Array=new Array();
    var Res1:Result609=new Result609();
    var Res2:Result610=new Result610();
    var Res3:Result611=new Result611();
    var Res4:Result612=new Result612();
    var Res5:Result613=new Result613();
    var i:int=0;

    public function EuroCup() {
        arr[1]=Res1;
        arr[2]=Res2;
        arr[3]=Res3;
        arr[4]=Res4;
        arr[5]=Res5;
    }
}
```

I think that is too lengthy. Is there any way to simplify it?
Here is the test.fla and test.as:[Download](http://www.renyi-nick.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/test.rar)
Whatever, thank u guys!

Comment: You might find [this branch of Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=actionscript) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Restructuring:

```
public class EuroCup extends Sprite {
    private var arr:Array;

    public function EuroCup() {
        arr = [ new Result609(), new Result610(),
                new Result611(), new Result612(), new Result613()
              ];
    }
}
```

Then use results as arr[0], arr[1] and so on. Also, if you have several sprites to listen clicks on, with similar listeners, you can connect all such sprites to single listeners and use event.target to distinguish them, where event is MouseEvent. Or place them into container and create one listener to that container - again, event.target will tell what sprite is clicked.
And yet two things - every time you see `new Array()`, replace it with `[]` - its faster and shorter. And place all code into constructor, not class body - it will be compiled to be executed faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can/should use a Dictionary for associations between the grey rects and the images to display.

```
package {
  public class EuroCup {

    private var _children:Array, _current:Sprite, _map:Dictionary;

    public function EuroCup() {
      super();
      initialize();
    }

    protected function initialize():void {
      _children = [];
      _map = new Dictonary();

      // i don't know the image's symbol name.
      // _map[_children[_children.length] = new Result609()] = new SYMBOL_NAME();

      for each(var child:Sprite in _children) {
        child.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_handler);
      }
    }

    private function click_handler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
      if (_current) {
        _current.visible = false; // or use fading, etc
      }

      _current = _map[event.currentTarget] as Sprite;

      if (_current) {
        _current.visible = true; // or use fading, etc
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option for simplifying the code would be to associate the `sp` and `Res` instances with each other by identity, using a *Dictionary*. That allows you to avoid the work of tracking array indices, which is half of the reason you have separate event handler methods. Once the instances are associated by identity, then you can use the *currentTarget* property of a dispatched event to determine which element in the Dictionary you want to show on the stage.

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

public class test extends Sprite
{
    var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    var visibleResult:MovieClip;

    public function test()
    {
        dict[sp1]=new Result609();
        dict[sp2]=new Result610();
        dict[sp3]=new Result611();
        dict[sp4]=new Result612();
        dict[sp5]=new Result613();

        sp1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse);
        sp2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse);
        sp3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse);
        sp4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse);
        sp5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,clickmouse);
    }

    private function clickmouse(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(visibleResult)
        {
            removeChild(visibleResult);
        }
        var Res:MovieClip = dict[evt.currentTarget] as MovieClip;
        addChild(Res);
        Res.x=300;
        Res.y=400;
        visibleResult=Res;
    }
}
}
```

If you expect to have more than 5 `sp` instances in the application, then you could use a loop to assign the event listeners. But for less than 10 instances, you probably don't gain much from a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a more simple version; add only one event listener and use `Event.target` to determine on which item is clicked, using a switch-statement.

This is helpful if the buttons should do different things.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public var sp1:Sprite;
        public var sp2:Sprite;
        public var sp3:Sprite;

        public function Test()
        {  
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleClick);
        }

        private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("Clicked on: " + event.target)
            switch (event.target)
            {
                case this.sp1:
                {
                    // do something here
                    break;
                }
                case this.sp2:
                {
                    // do something here
                    break;
                }
                case this.sp3:
                {
                    // do something here
                    break;
                }
                default
                {
                    trace("No handler defined for: " + event.target)
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

However, you can also make smart use of it's type. Let's say all you buttons extend a custom class called `CustomButton`, and they all need to do the same (like call a function), but with a parameter based on it's id.

This is helpful if the buttons should basically do the same thing.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {  
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleClick);
        }

        private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (event.target is CustomButton)
            {
                var button:CustomButton = event.target as CustomButton; // you're now sure it's a CustomButton
                this.showById(button.id); // let's say CustomButton has a public var 'id'
            }
        }

        private function showById(id:int):void
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Tip**: Always start your class+filename with a capital. Variables start with capitals. This is very common in the actionscript world.